# Изменить передаваемый в декоратор аргумент

Tags: python-3.x, декоратор

Как мне, допустим, умножить args на какое-нибудь число? `args * 2` выдает ошибку

```
def main(args):
  def wrapping():
    return args
  return wrapping()

@main
def factorial(n):
  if n == 0:
    return 1
  else:
    return n * factorial(n - 1)
print(factorial(5))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [3]: def decorator(func):
   ...:     def wrapper(n):
   ...:         return func(n * 2)
   ...:     return wrapper
   ...:

In [4]: @decorator
   ...: def foo(n):
   ...:     return n
   ...:

In [5]: foo(10)
Out[5]: 20
```

Также можно передавать параметр в декоратор:

```
In [7]: def decorator(x):
   ...:     def wrapper(func):
   ...:         def inner(n):
   ...:             return func(n * x)
   ...:         return inner
   ...:     return wrapper
   ...:

In [8]: @decorator(5)
   ...: def foo(n):
   ...:     return n
   ...:

In [9]: foo(10)
Out[9]: 50
```

Answer (score 1):

Декоратор принимает в качестве аргумента оригинальную функцию, и обычно возвращает функцию, которая принимает те же аргументы, что и оригинальная, и возвращает результат ее вызова этими аргументами.

Например, чтобы удвоить аргумент декорируемой функции, можно сделать так

```py
def main(f):        # f - это декорируемая функция
  def wrapping(n):  # эта функция заместит оригинальную, должна принимать тот же аргумент
    return f(2 * n) # и вызывать оригинальную функцию с удвоенным аргументом
  return wrapping   # возвращаем функцию

@main
def square(x):
    return x * x

print(square(5)) # 100
```

Только с факториалом это не сработает, потому, что внутри факториала будет рекурсивно вызываться уже декорированная функция, а значит аргумент будет бесконечно расти, и вызовет переполнение стека, зато можно сделать функцию, которая будет удваивать *результат*, а не аргумент, тогда вычисление завершится, хоть и тоже немного с неожиданным результатом

```py
def main2(f):
  def wrapping(n):
    return 2 * f(n)
  return wrapping

@main2
def factorial(n):
  if n == 0:
    return 1
  else:
    return n * factorial(n - 1)

print(factorial(5)) # 7680
```

> **2** * 5 * (**2** * 4 * (**2** * 3 * (**2** * 2 * (**2** * 1 * (**2** * 1))))) = 7680

Comment: Спасибо, вывод один, задание не решится с таким методом факториала, переделал код и просто умножил на число, все вышло, благодарю.